# moment.js IN ember not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ember.js

I have to add current date and time to my UI . I have installed ember plugin to my app moment.js but it is working in chrome but is showing invalid date in the IE.

I have added moment code in my model-

```
Date: function() {
        return moment(new Date(parseFloat(this.get('createOn'))).toLocaleString()).format('MMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    }.property('createOn')
```

Any solution to make it work in IE too.

Comment: do you have an example of invalid date ? Is it different in Chrome and IE by some hours ? ... it can be the effect of language settings in browsers, so there will be different time zone ... try utc() method in moment and compare.

Answer (score 2):

Date parsing is different among browsers (especially IE).

Please use moment.js to normalize your parsing:

```
return moment('X', this.get('createOn')).format('MMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

See [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) for more parsing, and formatting options.